# mysql syntax error 1064 at line 194 add foreign key for many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

help me please. I get the following message when I try to run the sql commands:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 194: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
    ADD CONSTRAINT VFSGRPUSR_REF_VFSGRP
        FOREIGN KEY (VFSGRP)
        REFERENCES `VFS' at line 1
```

I'm trying to implement a many-to-many relationship.

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `VFSGRPUSR`;

CREATE TABLE `VFSGRPUSR`
(
  `VFSGRP` INTEGER REFERENCES VFSGRP(VFSGRP_ID),
  `VFSUSR` INTEGER REFERENCES VFSUSR(VFSUSR_ID),
  PRIMARY KEY (`VFSGRP`, `VFSUSR`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET utf8;

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `VFSUSR`;

CREATE TABLE `VFSUSR`
(
  `VFSUSR_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `DEPARTMENT` INTEGER,
  `FIRSTNAME` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `SURNAME` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `LOGIN` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` BLOB,
  `TOKEN` BLOB,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`VFSUSR_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT VFSUSR_REF_DEPARTMENT FOREIGN KEY (DEPARTMENT) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (DEPARTMENT_ID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET utf8;

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `VFSGRP`;

CREATE TABLE `VFSGRP`
(
  `VFSGRP_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `GROUPNAME` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`VFSGRP_ID`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET utf8;

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ALTER TABLE VFSGRPUSR(
    ADD CONSTRAINT VFSGRPUSR_REF_VFSGRP
        FOREIGN KEY (VFSGRP)
        REFERENCES `VFSGRP`(VFSGRP_ID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET utf8;

ALTER TABLE VFSGRPUSR(
    ADD CONSTRAINT VFSGRPUSR_REF_VFSUSR
        FOREIGN KEY (VFSUSR)
        REFERENCES `VFSUSR`(VFSUSR_ID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET utf8;

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to also set `ENGINE` and `CHARSET`? Just use:

```
ALTER TABLE VFSGRPUSR
    ADD CONSTRAINT VFSGRPUSR_REF_VFSGRP
        FOREIGN KEY (VFSGRP)
        REFERENCES VFSGRP(VFSGRP_ID);
```

And refer to the official documentation for available syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: eclipse is strange. I've tried it before but it seems probably eclipse doesn't like me. Maybe hidden characters! Thank you very much.